# How to generate heading for columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

i generate excel using Larvel-Excel this is my function

```
`\Excel::create('JOBS', function($excel) {

    $excel->sheet('2015', function($sheet) {
        $jobs = \App\Job::all();
        foreach($jobs as $row){
            $data=array($row->id,$row->description,$row->vessel,$row->invoice_value);
            $sheet->fromArray(array($data),null,'A1',false,false);
        }
 });})->download('csv');
```

im getting out put like this correct but i want to set first row as column heading **ID, Description, vessel, Value** any idea??

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: i tried to get all the data in jobs table and generate document its working perfect but i want set heading fro every column in very first row

Comment: @PrudentialDeveloper so you want the first row to be "ID | Description | Vessel | Invoice Value"?

Comment: @Bogdan yes you correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the additional row with the headings before the `foreach` loop, the same way you add each data row:

```php
\Excel::create('JOBS', function ($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('2015', function ($sheet) {
        $jobs = \App\Job::all();

        // Add heading row
        $data = array('ID', 'Description', 'Vessel', 'Invoice Value');
        $sheet->fromArray(array($data), null, 'A1', false, false);

        // Add data rows
        foreach ($jobs as $row) {
            $data = array($row->id, $row->description, $row->vessel, $row->invoice_value);
            $sheet->fromArray(array($data), null, 'A1', false, false);
        }
    });
})->download('csv');
```

Comment: :) :) :) i waste 3 hours :( :( :(

Comment: can you this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783725/how-to-ignore-gide-when-we-download-document-as-a-pdf-using-dompdf-dompdf)